# Prove the two subspaces are equals to ${F^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$\eqalign{
  & W = \{ (0,b,c):b,c \in F\}   \cr 
  & U = \{ (a,a,a):a \in F\}  \cr} $$

Prove that:
$${F^3} = W \oplus U$$

A direction would be nice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that the sum $W+U$ is direct. That is, show that $w+u=w'+u'$ implies $w=w'$ and $u=u'$ (this means intuitively that the subspaces don't overlap). Then show that any vector in $F^3$ can be written as a sum of a vector in $W$ and a vector in $U$.

Comment: Can you explain me how to show the second part? (any vector in $F^3$ can be written as a sum of $u+w$)

Comment: Take a vector in $F^3$, $(x,y,z)$. We want to write $(x,y,z)=u+w$. The first component of $w$ is zero no matter what. Then what does $u$ HAVE to be? Then you should be able to figure out what $w$ is.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that

$$
\mathbb{F}^3 = W + U
$$

and

$$
W \cap U = \left\{ 0 \right\}
$$

These two imply that $\mathbb{F}^3 = W \oplus U$.